# How to extend or merge interfaces in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, interface

I am creating a custom collection class in VBA, whose members must implement two interfaces. One is a library interface `IComparable` which allows me to sort my collection, the other is a home-made interface `ImyObject` which guarantees certain properties of the members of the class. I ensure only the correct objects are added to my collection by having the following `add` procedure:

```
Public Sub add(item As variant)
    If TypeOf item Is IComparable And TypeOf item Is ImyObject Then
        'add to collection
    Else
        'raise error
```

Which requires `item`'s class to have

```
Implements ImyObject
Implements IComparable
```

I don't like this much, and would prefer to have a single interface `ImyComparableObject`, so my add procedure looks like

```
Public Sub add(item As ImyComparableObject)
    'item implements both by default
```

Why? Well a few reasons

- I don't find `TypeOf item Is ...` syntactically hugely enlightening *(but maybe just because I'm new to interfaces)*
- `ImyObject` should only really ever be used in conjunction with `IComparable`, so a single interface merging both would ensure the compiler spots this
- If many interfaces are required, the `TypeOf ...` gets unwieldy, and if another collection class also wants the same add definition, there will be alot of repeated code to maintain

  - Of course, the checks could all go in a function instead, but then errors are less traceable, and if the check has to be used by other collection classes too, then you need the function in a whole separate public module. It will get messy.
  - The best place to have the checks would be in the interface definition, as then the compiler can spot problems

---

#### What I've tried

My initial thinking was that `ImyInterface` could specify the particular methods of the objects my collection holds, and *also* specify that they must implement `IComparable`.

Since `ImyInterface` should always be used alongside `IComparable`, it makes sense to put the `IComparable` requirement in the `ImyInterface` definition. This gives an `ImyInterface` which looks like the following:

```
Implements mscorlib.IComparable
'This does sort of work;
'Anything implementing `ImyInterface` raises a compiler error
'if `Implements IComparable` is not also present

Public Function IComparable_CompareTo(ByVal obj As Variant) As Long
    'don't really want this, but it was the only way to get the interface to compile
End Function

Public Property Get sortingValue() As Double
End Property
```

But the resulting example object class which implements `ImyInterface` is just a mess, because as well as

```
ImyInterface_IComparable_CompareTo
```

it needs another (redundant)

```
IComparable_CompareTo
```

to compile, and even then there's too many underscores for the whole thing to compile (I'm guessing).

---

I really want to merge `IComparable` and `ImyInterface` into one super-interface that only needs a single `Implements`, but:

- I can't merge the code manually because `IComparable` is from a library
- Even if I could, I'm not sure the methods that require `IComparable` objects would still recognise the super-interface

### TLDR;

So is there any way to merge multiple interfaces, so that functions specifying each will accept the merged version? And if not, is there a better way to enforce multiple interfaces of an argument for a routine? Or do I just have to check manually if the types are correct, and raise a runtime error if not?

Comment: This is discussed in VB6s' Help. Remember the language of VB6 IS VBA (with a different forms package). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242080(v=vs.60).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241728(v=vs.60).aspx. The underlying technologies are explained here COM and Automation (Excel, VBA, and Automation were designed for each other) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663262(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: VBA doesn't have inheritance, so "merging" interfaces is not possible, and in any case, would go against the Interface Segregation Principle. As much as multiple `TypeOf` expressions are tedious, that's how VBA works.